# Best practice for deploying machine learning web app with Flask

Tags: python, flask, gensim

Hoping you can help. I’m creating a web app with python and Flask. One of the the things that my web app will do is provide a smart document search. You can enter text and it will fetch results of documents similar to the portion of text you entered.

I’ve used Flask for the front end to serve the HTML, manage any DB interactions required and display results. It will pass the query through to a Gensim similarity model and query it.

My question here is what is the best way to host these? I’ve explored loading the model as part of loading flask but it slows things down quite a lot (it’s c. 6gb in memory) but it works. I can then query the model quite easily as it’s all within the same program scope.

My concern is that this would then not be scalable and possibly not best practice and that I may be better to host the model separately and make API calls to it from my Flask web app.

Thoughts and views would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts are definitely on the right track.

Yes, you should separate the hosting of the model from your web app. Your suggestion of an API is a good one. Even if in the beginning it is all hosted on one machine, it is still worth doing this separation.

Once you are hosting this separately via an API, then as your web app has more users, it becomes easy to scale the model API.

Whether by launching more instances and balancing requests. Or, depending on requirements, you could add scalability and robustness via messaging, like Rabbitmq, or a mix of the two.

For example, some systems that access extremely large datasets, return a response via email to let you know your answer is ready to download or view. In this case, you may host one instance of the model, and put requests in q queue to answer one by one.

If you need very fast responses from your model, then you are likely to scale via more instances and balancing.

Both options above can be rolled out yourself, using open source solutions, or you can go straight to managed services in the cloud that will auto scale via either of these methods.

If you are just producing this project yourself with no funding, then you most likely do not want to start by using managed services in the cloud, as these will auto scale your bank account in the wrong direction.

The above solutions allow you to make changes, update the model, even use a different one, and release it on its own as long as it still conforms to the API.

Separation of boundaries in data, and responsibilities in behaviour are important in having a scalable and maintainable architecture.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look in to hosting as an API call. The Gensim model itself would just return a set of document IDs and similarity scores. I would then need to fetch the detail of those IDs from the DB that stores info on the docs ingested within the model. Would you propose the DB fetching happens on the Flask web app or the Flask hosted model? I'm leaning towards it staying with the web app as I use SQLAlchemy there and it would all stay within the ORM.

Comment: Good question. Im trying to keep my answer as generic as possible, as the amount of solutions and other information that could be added here is quite large. You may even want to do these database calls via another API, so that it is also a scalable solution away from your webapp. At the beginning, this may not be important, so you could put it in flask, and write it like it was an API. Dont do the db calls directly from your controller. The controller should call the model API, get a response, then call the db API, which should be in its own package in your flask app.

Comment: For now ill leave the part on how to handle an ORM once you separate parts of your project

Comment: Thanks for the responses, will get cracking on that.